# Displaying imaginary number

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mj07.png)I'm trying to create a calculator to display values that involved imaginary numbers. Right now i am unable to display any result on my program. Also is there anyway for me to create space between the input boxes. How can i also add an expandable container that contains text upon clicking the logo on the bottom right in grey. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:extended_math/extended_math.dart';


main()
{
  runApp(MaterialApp (
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: reflectioncoefficient(),
  ));
}

class reflectioncoefficient extends StatefulWidget {
  const reflectioncoefficient({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<reflectioncoefficient> createState() => reflectioncoefficientState();
}

class reflectioncoefficientState extends State<reflectioncoefficient> {
  double Rzl = 0;
  double Izl = 0;
  double Rzo =0;
  double Izo = 0;
  TextEditingController controller1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller2 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller3 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller4 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller5 = TextEditingController();
  late double result=0 ;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Calculator'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0 , top:50.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [

              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child:SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 170,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: controller1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Real ZL",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(child:
                  SizedBox(

                    height: 100,
                    width: 170,
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: controller2,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Imaginary ZL",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                      ),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child:SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 170,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: controller3,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Real Zo",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child:SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 170,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: controller4,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Imaginary Zo",
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20))
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child:SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 10,
                        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                          Rzl = double.parse(controller1.text);
                          Izl = double.parse(controller2.text);
                          Rzo = double.parse(controller3.text);
                          Izo = double.parse(controller4.text);
                          final zlvalue = Complex(re:Rzl , im:Izl) ;
                          final zovalue = Complex(re:Rzo , im:Izo) ;
                          final rcvalue = ((zlvalue)-(zovalue))/((zlvalue)+(zovalue));
                          final rcvaluemod = rcvalue.module;
                          final rcvaluearg = rcvalue.argument;
                          final result = rcvalue.module + rcvalue.argument;
                          print(rcvalue);
                        }, child: Text('Reflection Coefficient ')),
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(child:
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 30, 0, 0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('Results:', style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle_rounded),
                      onTap: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: Share UI Snippet of what you're trying to achieve for better understanding of your problem statement.

Comment: @Prashant Hi i just attached the photo. Basically the value in the console ( -0.38461538461538464 + 0.07692307692307693i) is calculated from the inputs entered and is suppose to appear beside the result on the emulator however i have no idea how to display the complex number.